# Add 2 minutes in each rows in pentaho or Javascript

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have list of the data in 3 wave phase like

```
id      email               emailSchedular          wave phase
1       xyz@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         1
2       abc@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         1

3       pqr@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         2
4       lmn@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         2
5       yml@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         2

6       wqy@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         3
7       pol@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         3
```

I am using pentaho 7.1 version.

How to add 2 minutes in each wave phase.

**Expected output**

```
id      email               emailSchedular          wave phase
1       xyz@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         1
2       abc@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:02:00         1

3       pqr@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         2
4       lmn@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:02:00         2
5       yml@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:04:00         2

6       wqy@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:00:00         3
7       pol@gmail.com       2019-06-21 08:02:00         3
```

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TLRh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by the following steps:

1. If the incoming data is not sorted by the wave phase, then sort according to the wave phase using `Sort rows` step
2. One the data is sorted add `Add value fields changing sequence` step and give a name for the result field, give `0` for the `Start at Value` and `2` for the `Increment by` and in the `Field` give wave phase as the Init Sequence if value of it changes
3. Add `Calculator` step and use the calculation `Date A + B Minutes` and `Field A` will be emailSchedular and `Field B` will be the name of the result field you gave in the previous step and give an appropriate name for the `New field`

[Screen Shot of the Transformation with each step and output for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI3SI.png)

Comment: #Manu N Shirur, Thank you so much for replayed, I achieved this by using Add sequence and afterwards I used Modified javascript value

Comment: I have updated description , Please click on `enter image description here` link